# Is it possible for one to disable Google's suspicious login attempt detection?

Tags: google-account, security, authentication, mobile

I am traveling quite a bit and due to that, I'm being requested a confirmation code  by Google, which requires the use of a mobile phone I am unfortunately unable to use due to differing cell networks where I am. Google is my OpenID provider, including for Stack Exchange, and I use Google's products directly. I actually use Google Voice for connectivity, so I am fully locked out.

Besides switching OpenID providers and not using Google's services (a step that is extremely inconvenient), is there a way to disable this behavior so I don't have to deal with the catch-22 lockouts?

Comment: You know you can also use fixed codes (in batches of 10) instead of the SMSes, right? You can also disable the 2-step verification — _not recommended_.

Comment: @Alex I do not use 2-step verification by default, so it isn't enabled in the first place. I do a standard sign-in as I use a secure computer that I own.

Comment: Then maybe you should enable it and use the fixed codes instead of the SMSes when you are traveling. I don’t know what the confirmation code is in your case, but it seems as an ad-hoc 2-step verification—am I right?

Comment: @Alex Yes, it is a request for a verification from my mobile phone due to my login. However, 2-step would be difficult for regular logins as I'd be carrying around fixed codes for use near my regular location(where I also do not use the phone) and it would be difficult to interoperate with my mail client.

Comment: I doubt that you’ll be able to disable it, but that’s just a hunch that I can’t prove.

Comment: @Alex I made it in, as simply trying and retrying let me give my regular sign-in location instead. This is still not a fix.